# Newline WallPost Facebook C#

Tags: c#, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am using following code to Post on facebook from my c# .net application:

```
   var fb = new FacebookClient(token);
   string url = string.Format("{0}/{1}", uid, "feed");
   var argList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   argList["message"] = phought; //message to be posted
   argList["link"] = VIDEOURL;
   object postId = fb.Post(url, argList);
```

But when my post contains newline character for eg:

```
Hi
I 
am
going
out
```

It is displayed as:

`Hi \ni \nam \ngoing\nout`

I want my code to display the output as it is on the facebook wall as i have shared without showing html chars kindly help

Answer (score 0):

The below code definitely works:

```
var fb= new FacebookClient(token);
fb.Post("me/feed", new {message = "line 1\r\nline 2"});
```

On FB, this posts:

```
line 1 
line 2
```

So you should look at your input string "phought" for the problem!

Comment: Sorry the message contains the same character as you have shown above but same is displayed on facebook wall as well so not working

Comment: So, run the exact same code above - and tell me what appears on FB.  So when I say exact same code, I mean with no changes at all ...